# MS Word C# Get revisions colors

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in, revision

I am trying to display my own panel with revisions. At the current moment code looks like this:

```
foreach (Revision revision in Doc.Revisions.AsParallel())
{
     // Some staff
}
```

This way I can get all of the revisions (possibly with duplicates, but don't mind). How can I get color of each revision? MS Word itself draws each revision with its own color, and I want to draw each revision in my panel with the same color.

Comment: The Revision has a [`Style` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.revision.style.aspx)

Comment: @stuartd `revision.Style` is not working for me, exception: "Required object is not available" (translated this message myself from localized message), HelpUrl: wdmain11.chm#25332.

Comment: As far as I know, the color of revisions is not exposed in the object model. You may specify fixed colors though (an application-wide option) as described in [Advanced Track Changed Options](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Advanced-Track-Changes-Options-46207970-9f4d-4a9b-9f84-5155a394dd1e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and then use these colors (that are then no longer different per author though)